# How mamy trailing zeroes in 1000! Using G.P. or A.P.?

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

I figured out the way to calculate the number of trailing zeroes in 1000! Where ! Denotes factorial but I dont know how to use A.P. OR G.P.
Original question:1000! is divisible by 10^n , find the largest possible integer value of n.
My way to solve:I calculated the number of factors of 10 by dividing 1000/10  and got 100 then I knew that 5*2 is also 10 but factors of 2 are more than that of 5 so only calculated factors of 5 and that are hundred so total 200 factors of ten, but 25 has 2 factors of 5 so 40 more factors of 10 , and going on with powers of 5 I got value of n as 249.
But indont know how to use GP or AP  to solve the question , is there a way to do so if yes how?

Comment: Why do you want to use GP or AP to solve this? I can't see how to do that either. (I agree with your 249.)

Comment: Because it is asked in exercise of progressions